# ayuda, Crear DAO con clases heredadas

Tags: oracle, jsp, class

estoy realizando un proyecto el cual la clase tiene la siguiente estructura

package Modelo;
public class ClProducto
{
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcionHTML;
    private ClUnidadMedida unidadMedidaId;
    private ClCategoria categoriaId;
    private ClImpuesto impuestoId;
    private int eliminado;

```
public ClProducto(int id, String nombre, String descripcionHTML, ClUnidadMedida unidadMedidaId, ClCategoria categoriaId, ClImpuesto impuestoId, int eliminado) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.descripcionHTML = descripcionHTML;
    this.unidadMedidaId = unidadMedidaId;
    this.categoriaId = categoriaId;
    this.impuestoId = impuestoId;
    this.eliminado = eliminado;
}

public ClProducto() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDescripcionHTML() {
    return descripcionHTML;
}

public void setDescripcionHTML(String descripcionHTML) {
    this.descripcionHTML = descripcionHTML;
}

public ClUnidadMedida getUnidadMedidaId() {
    return unidadMedidaId;
}

public void setUnidadMedidaId(ClUnidadMedida unidadMedidaId) {
    this.unidadMedidaId = unidadMedidaId;
}

public ClCategoria getCategoriaId() {
    return categoriaId;
}

public void setCategoriaId(ClCategoria categoriaId) {
    this.categoriaId = categoriaId;
}

public ClImpuesto getImpuestoId() {
    return impuestoId;
}

public void setImpuestoId(ClImpuesto impuestoId) {
    this.impuestoId = impuestoId;
}

public int getEliminado() {
    return eliminado;
}

public void setEliminado(int eliminado) {
    this.eliminado = eliminado;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClProducto{" + "id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", descripcionHTML=" + descripcionHTML + ", unidadMedidaId=" + unidadMedidaId + ", categoriaId=" + categoriaId + ", impuestoId=" + impuestoId + ", eliminado=" + eliminado + '}';
}
```

}

y el controller es el siguiente

public ArrayList obtenerTodos() throws SQLException
    {

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<ClProducto> object = new ArrayList<ClProducto>();

    try
    {
        ConexionBD conn = new ConexionBD();
        String stm = "{call PKG_PRODUCTO.SP_TODOS (?)}";
        OracleCallableStatement cst = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.getConnection().prepareCall(stm);
        cst.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cst.execute();
        rs = (ResultSet)cst.getObject(1);
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            ClProducto c = new ClProducto();

            c.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            c.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
            c.setDescripcionHTML(rs.getString(3));
            //c.setUnidadMedidaId(clUni.getId(rs.getInt(4)));
            //c.setCategoriaId(clCat.getId(rs.getInt(5)));
            //c.setImpuestoId(clImp.getId(rs.getInt(6)));
            c.setEliminado(rs.getInt(7));
            object.add(c);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error : "+e);
    }
    return object;

}
```

mi pregunta es ¿como hago para agregar la unidadmedidaId, categoriaId e impuestoId a la lista? en general son las lineas comentadas
de igual manera en el servlet..

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        DAOProducto dao = new DAOProducto();

```
   String nombre = request.getParameter("txtNombreProducto");
   String descripcionHTML = request.getParameter("txtDescripcionHTML");
   int unidadMedida = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cmbUnidadMedida"));
   int categoria = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cmbCategoria"));
   if(!nombre.equals("") || !descripcionHTML.equals("") || unidadMedida<1 || categoria<1)
   {
       ClProducto c = new ClProducto();
       ClUnidadMedida c1 = new ClUnidadMedida();
       ClCategoria c2 = new ClCategoria();

       c.setNombre(nombre);
       c.setDescripcionHTML(descripcionHTML);
       c1.setId(unidadMedida);
       c2.setId(categoria);
       //aca tiene que ir c.setCategoriaId();
       dao.agregar(c);
   }




    ArrayList<ClProducto> lista = dao.obtenerTodos();
    request.setAttribute("MostrarListaProductos", lista);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WebPages/productosCRUD.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```